# Numbering Static Map Markers

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to label markers on a static map with numbers beyond 5 or 10.  The current limitation of 5 custom markers along with the limitation of only adding a single character to the label is preventing me from this.  Is there any way to do this?  Essentially, I want the static map to look just like the interactive map.  See pic. [interactiveMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6UyW.jpg)

I've tried adding more than 5, markers after number 5 come out as the standard default marker.

I've also tried labels which only work up to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to have more than 10 markers with different labels is to use letters (A-Z).

There is a feature request to allow markers labels with more than 1 character:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153766616